# Why does the position of my button affect the position of my list?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a webpage using html and css and I have positioned a horizontal list along the bottom of the page, but when I add a button to the centre of the page, it pushed the list further down the page.

```css
 .navigation {
   max-width: 700px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   margin-top: 700px;
 }
 .navigation ul {
   list-style: none;
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
 }
 .navigation ul li {
   display: table-cell;
   text-align: center;
 }
 .navigation ul li a {
   padding: 5px 5px;
   width: 100%;
   font-family: "calibri";
 }
 .button {
   -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #fce2c1;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #fce2c1;
   box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #fce2c1;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #FF9933), color- stop(1, #fb9e25));
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #FF9933 5%, #fb9e25 100%);
   filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient (startColorstr='#FF9933', endColorstr='#fb9e25');
   background-color: #FF9933;
   -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
   -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
   border-top-left-radius: 0px;
   -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
   -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
   border-top-right-radius: 0px;
   -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
   -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0px;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
   -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
   -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
   text-indent: 0px;
   display: inline-block;
   color: #00000;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 35px;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-style: normal;
   height: 90px;
   line-height: 100px;
   width: 500px;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-align: center;
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #cc9f52;
   margin-left: 550px;
   margin-top: 300px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>website</title>
<body>

  <a href="#" class="button">UPLOAD</a>

  <div class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Sign Up</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Login</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">RFR</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class navigation has margin-top:700px which means it wants to position itself 700px below the button you're adding. So when the page was empty, your nav would position itself 700px below the top of your screen (because there are no other elements on the screen), but when the button is introduced your nav is positioned 700px below it.

I would guess you're looking for a 'sticky footer' (where the nav will appear at the bottom of an empty screen, but will require you to scroll down if you have a page full of content) or possibly a footer with a fixed position (always at the bottom of the screen).

To implement a fixed footer, you could change your navigation class as follows:

```
.navigation {
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    bottom: 0;
    position:absolute;
}
```

`bottom:0;` means you want your nav to be 0px from the bottom of your screen. `position:fixed` tells the element to position itself using the browser window, not other elements (such as the button).

Check it out on this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shv6bjf3/)

Comment: Thanks, but how would I fix the position at the bottom of the screen then without using margin-top: 700px?

Comment: I updated the answer with an example. The key point is that if you're using margin-top, it's positioning itself relative to elements above it.

Answer (score 0):

change the value of navigation margin-top to 200px or below.

---

```
.navigation {
max-width: 700px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 200px;
```

Answer (score 0):

@zigg76 if you are aiming for a sticky footer you can use the following css and edit it a little to your satisfaction

```
.myfooter
  {
   position:fixed;
   bottom:0;
  }
```